# Imprimir return de una clase en otra clase en PHP

Tags: php

¿Como podría imprimir el return de la variable $formData en una clase en PHP?

```html
function location_form_handler($formData) // Use a different function name for each form
{
    $formName = 'General'; // change this to your form's name
    $fieldName = 'carrera'; // change this to your field's name
    $newFieldName = $fieldName . '_carrera';
    return form_with_pipes_handler($formName, $fieldName, $newFieldName, $formData);
}

function my_custom_function($cf7) {

$req_dump = print_r($_REQUEST, TRUE);
$fp = fopen('request.log', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $req_dump);
fclose($fp);

}
```

Quisiera imprimir el valor de $formData en el request.log ¿Como podría hacer?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Podés imprimir el valor de una variable a un archivo desde cualquier parte de PHP con **file_put_contents()**:

```
function location_form_handler($formData) {
    // Guardamos el valor de $formData en request.log
    file_put_contents('request.log', $formData, FILE_APPEND);

    $formName = 'General'; // change this to your form's name
    $fieldName = 'carrera'; // change this to your field's name
    $newFieldName = $fieldName . '_carrera';
    return form_with_pipes_handler($formName, $fieldName, $newFieldName, $formData);
}
```